# Play Store error message 'To view this content, install and set up a web browsing app'

Tags: android, browser, google-play

About 3 weeks back, I noticed whenever I tried to click on link in message I'd sent to myself to install some app, I had message pop up saying 'To view this content, install and set up a web browsing app'.  Prior to this, phone worked correctly.  I also noticed others had same problem in 2021, and they were advised it was a temp problem on Google's side, and would be fixed in 2 weeks, so I'm not sure why I'm now seeing this message.  Clearly not a 2 week problem.

Looked in 'Developer Options' but found nothing there it could be.  Then I Checked to make sure Google browser is my default browser, which it was.  Now I don't know what to do, short of tossing/replacing it.  Has anyone found a way to fix this problem yet?

UPDATE:  I found the fix on REDDIT.  Now my android phone works again. Here it is, for anyone else that has this problem: Go into the System App Settings for the Play Store.  Select "Open by default" -> Select "Open supported links" -> Select "Ask every time".  That's it.  Worked like a charm for me.

Comment: This happens when you have invalid playstore links. If it happens with anyone please check the link first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bit of a pain to fix, but setting Play Store's `Allow App to Open Supported Links` to `Ask every time` worked for me.

This can be a bit deep in the menus, here's one way to get there:

1.

[image: Settings]

2.

[image: Apps & Notifications]

3.

[image: Google Play Store]

4.

[image: Open by default]

5.

[image: Open supported links]

6.

[image: Ask every time]

7. Done, hopefully it works now!

Comment: yes, hopefully it works now!  Thank you so much for providing such detailed and clear instructions - I was able to follow them completely, to the end, with each step showing as I completed them exactly as you'd shown.  Appreciate it!!